# Remove linear-gradient from Background Image

Tags: css, css-selectors

The Problem is i have bundled up linear-gradient with background image. The gradient puts a black overlay over the image. Is there any way I can remove the gradient ? The image should stay the same.

```
background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url( http://localhost/wordpressfree/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/block1.jpg );
```

I tried background-color:none !important; and many more properties but it doesn't work. I'd appreciate if any one knows any way to deal with THIS particular issue. Google didn't help.

**EDIT: This is on a client site, So I can't edit the stylesheet. I need a way to override the gradient part. And also the background image can be changed by users(can't hard code image). I can only provide users CSS code that will be added on top of page. so overriding gradient is my best bet.**

Comment: `background: url( http://localhost/wordpressfree/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/block1.jpg );` is this not what your looking for

Comment: Nah, This is on a client side so the best I can do is to provide a code to over ride the gradient without removing background image. So I can't edit stylesheet

Comment: you can tell it to do 2 things. first tell it to be: `background: none;` then further down your stylesheet tell it how you want the background to be styled

Comment: this should work `background-image: url(http://localhost/wordpressfree/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/block1.jpg);` if not add !important

Comment: What are you editing. Is your stylesheet that you are adding in above or below the stylesheet that you cant edit. Also is it an iframe that you are trying to edit

Comment: It's on a user's site. I can provide the user CSS code that will be added on top of that page.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `linear-gradient` portion.

```
background: url(http://localhost/wordpressfree/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/block1.jpg);
```

Comment: Explanation added, Since one a client's site,  I need a way to over ride that Gradient part without removing background image.

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url(http://localhost/wordpressfree/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/block1.jpg);
```

or:

```
background-image: url(../images/help/community.svg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: Please see the added explanation.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

As the background contains two images (the linear-gradient and the url image below it), to remove the linear-gradient image could be achieved by setting the background-size of this first image to "0% 0%", while the second image (the url) can remain with the default size (e.g. "cover"). So for example:

`background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url( http://localhost/wordpressfree/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/block1.jpg);`

`background-size: 0% 0%, cover;`

Next time, if you want to revitalise the linear-gradient then you just apply the updated background-size to both images. So:

`background-size: cover, cover;`

These properties could then be controlled on the client-side via classes, for example.